# Account not found when requesting OAuth token from google api

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api, google-oauth

I am trying to implement a call to Google OAuth API

A JWT is created from the following data:

```
  const jwtClaim = {
    "iss": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly",
    "aud": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "exp": 1588679460,
    "iat": 1588676460
  };
```

The following data is then sent:

```
  const data = {
    "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
    "assertion": "my_jwt_string"
  };
```

to the following endpoint

```
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  };

 fetch('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', options).then((res) => {
   console.log(res);
 })
```

But i am getting the following error:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid grant: account not found"}
```

How is it possible that with a valid client_id I am getting an error that the account doesnt exist?

Comment: "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",  that is not a valid grant type.   Why dont you use the client library?

Comment: the client button requires a login button as seen from the example here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js. I dont prefer to use a button like this at all in my front-end